# IOS: Convert comma delimited string to NSSet

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsset

I get some JSON from a web service that contains a comma delimited string that I wish to break into elements.

Because this is for a many to many relationship I tried grabbing it as an NSSet.  However, json seems to consist natively of strings so I need first to convert the comma delimited string into a set.

There are a lot of answers on SO and web on how to convert an array or set into a comma delimited string. There are also ways to convert a comma delimited string into an array such as:

```
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

But I can't find anything for converting the comma delimited string into an NSSet.

The string is of the form 1,2,3,4.

Can anyone suggest right way to do this.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Create the `NSSet` from the `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  NSSet<NSString*> *set = [NSSet setWithArray:[theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
```